# Nuxt 3 with vuetify 3 and ssr error, why?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use Nuxt 3 and Vuetify latest versions.
When I create `plugins/vuetify.ts` with base contents:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    ssr: true,
    components,
    directives,
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

And `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify']
  },
  vite: {
    define: {
      'process.env.DEBUG': false
    }
  }
})
```

I get an error in console `[nuxt] error caught during app initialization H3Error: Page not found: /_nuxt/node_modules/vuetify/src/util/defineComponent.tsx`

Why? And how to fix it?